# Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX parser

Tags: java, web-services, dependencies, jar

I've created a stand-alone web services client in Java. I'm able to generate the WSDL properly but when when i execute my run.bat file, I get the exception above long with the exception below. I googled for the exception shown in the title and found a .jar file that contained it. I added this to my JBOSS_HOME/lib directory as well as the Client/lib directory. not sure why i'm still seeing this. ANY advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX parser
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerFactory$UnmarshallerFactoryImpl.newUnmarshaller(UnmarshallerFactory.java:100)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.config.JBossWSConfigFactory.parse(JBossWSConfigFactory.java:76)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.config.JBossWSConfigFactory.getConfig(JBossWSConfigFactory.java:149)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initEndpointConfigMetaData(EndpointMetaData.java:872)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initEndpointConfig(EndpointMetaData.java:849)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.rebuildEndpointMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:292)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPortInternal(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPort(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:198)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:141)
    at com.firstcoverage.ws.client.om.WSStandAloneReportingSoapServiceService.getWSStandAloneReportingSoapServicePort(WSStandAloneReportingSoapServiceService.java:68)
    at com.firstcoverage.ws.client.StandAloneReportingSoapClientFactory.ConnectToFCStandAloneReportingSoapWS(StandAloneReportingSoapClientFactory.java:70)
    at com.firstcoverage.ws.client.StandAloneReportingSoapClientFactory.CreateInstance(StandAloneReportingSoapClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.firstcoverage.ws.client.Reporter.main(Reporter.java:89)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to create a new SAX parser
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.<init>(SaxJBossXBParser.java:96)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.<init>(UnmarshallerImpl.java:55)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerFactory$UnmarshallerFactoryImpl.newUnmarshaller(UnmarshallerFactory.java:96)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.<init>(SaxJBossXBParser.java:92)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like i had too many jar files. removed the local jar files referencing xerces and i was cool
ref: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/whydoigetjavalangclasscastexceptionorgapachexercesparsersxincludeawareparserconfigurationinas-5

Answer (score 1):

It could be not exact the same thing from the above link of the jobss site.
You might try to get your application using JAXB, JAXB-impl library from sun.
Here it forced to use org.jboss.xb.binding.